# Not able to see databases in symlinked folder

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

I created a folder on my Dropbox and then symlinked it to both of my computers that I use for development. The folder is working correctly and I can see all the files in it from both computers. The problem arises when I try and access the databases from my MacBook Air. When I open up MAMP Pro and start the web service I can't connect to my development sites, at least from one of my computers.

My questions are: Is this even a good idea to symlink the db folder for MAMP? 
If it is not then is the a smart way to develop locally on two machines?
Can I prompt phpMyAdmin to reindex the db folder so it can start accessing the databases?

I have tried shutting down both versions of the server software. I have restarted both machines. I am at a loss right now.

-Josh

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox can not be used for sharing a database. Its not a normal file that can be copied. 
There are a few options on working around this.

Use Mysqldump and export your databases then copy to dropbox. This would be every time you switch computers.

`mysqldump db_name`

Set up a SSH tunnel to connect to MySQL on the other computer.
        `ssh -fNg -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 myuser@remotehost.com`
        `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -u dbuser -p db`

Set up Multi-MySQL using bin logs. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-log.html